# jQuery SlimScroll Overflow issue with a Fixed Sidebar and BootStrap v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slimscroll

I am trying to develop a a page similar to the following: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/677U8/7/

I have a fixed sidebar div with a list of menu items which would popup out sub-menus or divs. I am using a jquery library called SlimScroller to create a facebook-styled scroller for the fixed sidebar div. I have another div on the side with a map in it and a div on the bottom which is a fixed footer.

The page is laid out in such a way that the side bar takes 15% of the screen and the rest is occupied by the map area.

When I hover over the list item in the sidebar, I wish to see the sub-menu pop out on hover. Due to overflow being hidden, this doesn't happen as shown in the image:

[image: overflow hidden]

```
.page-sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But when I force the overflow of sidebar to be visible using '!important' keyword I can see my sub-menu pop up on hover:

[image: overflow forced to be visible]

```
.page-sidebar {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I've tried to change the CSS on hover using JavaScript, but that doesn't work for some reason.

**Edit:**

Is there a solution to make sure that the Sidebar Scrolls as well as I can get the pop over with or without using JavaScript?

I currently have added the class .page-sidebar to make the popup appear. By doing so, the Sidebar doesn't scroll. If I remove the class .page-sidebar, the Sidebar Scrolls again, but this time the popup doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's the problem? Your fiddle is working how you want. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Morpheus, I have modified my question.

Yes, the current fiddle works as I want. But as you can observe, the Sidebar doesn't scroll in the fiddle.

In order to make the Sidebar Scroll, I have to modify the .page-sidebar class. By doing so, I can scroll the sidebar, but the popup won't display as desired.

Comment: @rand0m this is an old post, but I'm having similar issue, did You find any solution for the issue?